# How to customize the location of color bar in Seaborn heatmap?

Tags: python, seaborn, visualization, heatmap

I have the following code to create a heatmap. However, it creates an overlap of the color bar and the right axis text. The text has no problems, I want it to be in that length.

How can I locate the colorbar on the right/left side of the heatmap with no overlap?
I tried with "pad" parameter in cbar_kws but it didn't help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frI5z.jpg)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

PT=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(300,3), columns=list('ABC'))
miniPT=PT.iloc[:,:-1]
SMALL_SIZE = 8
MEDIUM_SIZE = 80
BIGGER_SIZE = 120    
plt.rc('font', size=MEDIUM_SIZE)          # controls default text sizes
plt.rc('axes', titlesize=MEDIUM_SIZE)     # fontsize of the axes title
plt.rc('axes', labelsize=MEDIUM_SIZE)    # fontsize of the x and y labels
plt.rc('xtick', labelsize=MEDIUM_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('ytick', labelsize=SMALL_SIZE)    # fontsize of the tick labels
plt.rc('legend', fontsize=MEDIUM_SIZE)    # legend fontsize
plt.rc('figure', titlesize=BIGGER_SIZE)  # fontsize of the figure title
plt.figure(figsize=(10, miniPT.shape[0]/5.2))
ax =sns.heatmap(miniPT, annot=False, cmap='RdYlGn')
for _, spine in ax.spines.items():
    spine.set_visible(True)
# second axis
asset_list=np.asarray(PT['C'])
asset_list=asset_list[::-1]
ax3 = ax.twinx()
ax3.set_ylim([0,ax.get_ylim()[1]])
ax3.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks())
ax3.set_yticklabels(asset_list, fontsize=MEDIUM_SIZE*0.6)
# colorbar
cbar = ax.collections[0].colorbar
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=MEDIUM_SIZE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was eventually move the colorbar to left side. This is the code and the output:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

PT = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(300, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, len(PT) / 5.2), gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [15, 15]})
sns.heatmap(PT.iloc[:, :-1], annot=False, cmap='RdYlGn', cbar_ax=ax0, ax=ax1)
for _, spine in ax1.spines.items():
    spine.set_visible(True)
# second axis
asset_list = np.asarray(PT['C'])
ax3 = ax1.twinx()
ax3.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim())
ax3.set_yticks(np.arange(len(PT)))
ax3.set_yticklabels(asset_list, fontsize=80)
# colorbar
ax0.tick_params(labelsize=80)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the overlap automatically adjusted by matplotlib, is to explicitly create subplots: one for the heatmap and another for the colorbar. `sns.heatmap`'s `cbar_ax=` parameter can be set to point to this subplot. `gridspec_kws=` is needed to set the relative sizes. At the end, `plt.tight_layout()` will adjust all the paddings to make everything fit nicely.

The question's code contains some strange settings (e.g. a fontsize of 80 is immense). Also, 300 rows will inevitably lead to overlapping text (the fontsize needs to be so small that non-overlapping text wouldn't be readable). Here is some more simplified example code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

PT = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
fig, (ax, cbar_ax) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, len(PT) / 5.2), gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [10, 1]})
sns.heatmap(PT.iloc[:, :-1], annot=False, cmap='RdYlGn', cbar_ax=cbar_ax, ax=ax)
for _, spine in ax.spines.items():
    spine.set_visible(True)
# second axis
asset_list = np.asarray(PT['C'])
ax3 = ax.twinx()
ax3.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
ax3.set_yticks(np.arange(len(PT)))
ax3.set_yticklabels(asset_list, fontsize=80)
# colorbar
cbar_ax.tick_params(labelsize=80)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

As the plot is quite large, here only the bottom part is pasted, with a link to the full plot.

[image: sns.heatmap with custom colorbar placement]

This is how it would look like with:

- fontsize 80 (Note that font sizes are measured in "points per inch", standard 72 points per inch);
- figure width of 20 inches (instead of 10);
- 300 rows

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

PT = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(300, 3), columns=list('ABC'))
fig, (ax, cbar_ax) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(20, len(PT) / 5.2), gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [15, 1]})
sns.heatmap(PT.iloc[:, :-1], annot=False, cmap='RdYlGn', cbar_ax=cbar_ax, ax=ax)
for _, spine in ax.spines.items():
    spine.set_visible(True)
# second axis
asset_list = np.asarray(PT['C'])
ax3 = ax.twinx()
ax3.set_ylim(ax.get_ylim())
ax3.set_yticks(np.arange(len(PT)))
ax3.set_yticklabels(asset_list, fontsize=80)
# colorbar
cbar_ax.tick_params(labelsize=80)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: 300 rows, fontsize 80]

Comment: Hi JohanC, 
Thanks for your suggestion. 
However, it doesn't help, since I need a solution specifically for my settings: I need 300 lines in the heatmap, and a text size of 80. There is also no issue with the overlapping text. All I want is to move the colorbar so there will be no overlap with the text.

I'd be glad to get any other solution :)

Comment: Well, what you ask is impossible.  This text with fontsize 80 is wider than the available width of 10 inches.  You can make a wider plot, but will still have extreme overlapping.

Comment: What about putting the color bar on the left side of the heatmap? Is it possible? (Again, keeping the 300 lines)

Comment: You can set the colorbar at the left via `fig, (cbar_ax, ax) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=..., gridspec_kw={'width_ratios': [1, 15]})`.  But that way the space will be just as occupied.  You still can't put all this text with fontsize 80 into 10 inches.